# How to define a connection string in Azure Websites for MySQL database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, azure

I have an issue on how to set the connection string in Azure Websites to connect to MySQL database.

I am developing ASP.NET MVC application hosted in Azure Webistes. It uses two databases: SQL Server in Azure itself and MySQL in a remote hosting.

In Visual Studio I use the .NET Connector provided by MySQL to generate the model, and the connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="myEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=myserver.com;user id=tom;password=tomspass;database=mydatabase&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

On the other, I have an script that recreates the environment for my application in Azure. It tells Azure to set two connections strings in Azure Websites configuration panel thus overriding the values in the web.config file. In the script I define them this way:

```
$connectionStrings = ( `
    @{Name = $sqlAppDatabaseName; Type = "SQLAzure"; ConnectionString = $sql.AppDatabase.ConnectionString}, `
    @{Name = "myEntities"; Type = "MySql"; ConnectionString = "metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=myserver.com;user id=productionuser;password=productionpassword;database=mydatabase&quot;"}
)
```

Unfortunately it does not work, when hitting code to access data in MySQL the following error appears:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection'.
```

If I remove the connection string for MySQL in Azure panel and use the one defined in the web.config file (with production values) there is no error works!

What I am doing wrong? Is not the connection defined correctly in the script? But how if it is the same of the web.config file?  It occurs to me this is because when defining the connection string in Azure the 'providerName' part of the is not set but why if it is already set in the web.config??

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: See if this article helps. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau thanks but it does not work. Thing is I am using Database First approach, the example looks like is not. :(

Comment: How does the connection string look like in the configuration panel on the portal after setting it with the script?

Comment: Additionally, I wonder how your current connection string works locally. The provider name should be MySql.Data.MySqlClient.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this as I don't have a MySQL database handy but I think you have 2 issues:

- The provider name part of the connection string is wrong, you should define it as such

`<add name="myEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=myserver.com;user id=tom;password=tomspass;database=mydatabase&quot;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />`

and in your Web.config replace

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory
      type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider
      invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

with

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity"/> 
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
      invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
      type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.2.0"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

- In the script, add ProviderType attribute

`$connectionStrings = ( 
        @{Name = $sqlAppDatabaseName; Type = "SQLAzure"; ConnectionString = $sql.AppDatabase.ConnectionString},`
        @{Name = "myEntities"; Type = "MySql"; ProviderType = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"; ConnectionString = "metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string="server=myserver.com;user id=productionuser;password=productionpassword;database=mydatabase""}
    )