# Azure ASP MVC Entity Framework App, with MySql, Cant connect

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, azure

Im working on a team project which was created in Visual Studio MVC with MySql. 
When testing everything locally it was fine. When i was ready to go live, i deployed the app through GitHub, everything went good, **but just no data**.

I was using a local connection string with user=root and password=password to MySql Workbench in VS Web.Config.

I have created a new connection on MySql to Azure server with username and password supplied, Connection tested fine.

I changed the connection string in web config to Azures server name , username and password(Not quite sure about the ConnString Alias though).

I commited these changes, but still nothing. I am a bit confused about the process to be honest. 
Not quite sure **how to move the existing local database model over to Azure**.

I would be grateful for any help, 
thanks J

[This is the app currently deployed](http://mechanictracker.azurewebsites.net/)

UPDATE:

Having Set up a linked ClearDb to my web app site, i made changes to the web config.

```
<add name="MTEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MechanicEntities.csdl|res://*/MechanicEntities.ssdl|res://*/MechanicEntities.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=(AZURE SERVER ADDRESS);user id=(AZURE SERVER ID);password=(AZURE SERVER PASSWORD);database=(CLEARDB LINKED DATABASE NAME);" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Should i make changes to this

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

I know these settings should be changed, i have tried a few things but to no avail, one method was [Here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533557/how-to-define-a-connection-string-in-azure-websites-for-mysql-database).

Im getting frustrated at this point as each change has to be comitted and deployed which is eating time.

Comment: You succeed to deploy the database to Azure?

Comment: I dont think so, is this done through ClearDB?

Comment: You need to have a ClearDB MySql Server Database. Do you use EF with Code First?

Comment: Its done through ET, i have created a ClearDB MySQL Database called MT, im aware there is connection string data within the portal-dashboard but im not sure how i would apply it?

Comment: [This](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/) should help you with connection string

Comment: Thanks mate but i already have that set up. Im just a bit lost as to the configuration of my webconfig